# How do I migrate data in tables to a new Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

How do I migrate application tables in an existing Cassandra cluster to a new cluster?

The new cluster has a different topology and token assignments to the source cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preparation

On the source cluster, take a snapshot of the relevant keyspaces using the `nodetool snapshot` command. For example:

```
$ nodetool snapshot <keyspace_name>
```

Here is an example where I take a snapshot of the `community` keyspace.

**STEP B1** - Create a snapshot:

```
$ nodetool snapshot community
Requested creating snapshot(s) for [community] with snapshot name [1591083719993] and options {skipFlush=false}
Snapshot directory: 1591083719993
```

The directory `1591083719993` name is a Unix timestamp for when the snapshot was created and is equivalent to June 2, 2020 7:41am GMT. There is one table called `users` in my example keyspace and the snapshot is located in the following directory structure:

```
data/
  community/
    users-6140f420a4a411ea9212efde68e7dd4b/
      snapshots/
        1591083719993/
          manifest.json
          mc-1-big-CompressionInfo.db
          mc-1-big-Data.db
          mc-1-big-Digest.crc32
          mc-1-big-Filter.db
          mc-1-big-Index.db
          mc-1-big-Statistics.db
          mc-1-big-Summary.db
          mc-1-big-TOC.txt
          schema.cql
```

For more info, see [Taking a snapshot in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsBackupTakesSnapshot.html).

### Tooling

Taking a snapshot needs to be carried out on all nodes in the cluster. It is preferable if you create them in parallel to make it simpler for you to identify the snapshot folders.

To achieve this, I recommend using tools you already have in your environment. If you are already using orchestration tools like Ansible, create the snapshots in parallel by running the command on all nodes simultaneously. Similarly, you can also script the restore operation so you can execute it in parallel using Ansible.

If you are not using orchestration tools, consider using Cluster SSH (`cssh`) or Parallel SSH (`pssh`) so you can run commands simultaneously on all nodes in your cluster.

### Cloning a table

**PREPARATION** - Create the application keyspace and table schema on the destination cluster. If necessary, use the `schema.cql` file in the snapshots folder as a guide.

Once the keyspace and table schema has been created, follow the procedure below to restore the tables.

**STEP 1** - Copy the snapshot to a temporary location so that the SSTable files are located in a directory with `keyspace_name/table_name`. For example:

```
$ cp -p \
    data/community/users-6140f420a4a411ea9212efde68e7dd4b/snapshots/1591083719993/* \
    /path/to/community/users/.
```

**STEP 2** - Load the data files to the destination cluster with the utility as follows:

```
$ sstableloader -d dest_node_ip1, dest_node_ip2 /path/to/community/users/
```

**STEP 3** - Repeat **steps 1 & 2** on the next node in the source cluster until the snapshots on ALL nodes have been loaded to the destination cluster.

Repeat the steps above on each table that you want to clone to the destination cluster.

For more info, see [Cassandra bulk loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html). Cheers!

---

For instructions on cloning application data to an "identical" cluster, see [How do I restore Cassandra snapshots to another cluster with identical configuration?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316497/).