# Can we just copy the data directory of production nodes to DR nodes if the prod Cassandra cluster is down?

Tags: cassandra

Requirement: Cassandra PROD container runs in one reqion and DR container runs in another region.

1. Take full snapshot of data folder and incremental snapshot of data folder
2. If PROD region goes down, make DR container up pointing to data folder copied from PROD region.

will above scenario work? Because PROD and DR cluster nodes numbers are different, we cannot use nodetool and sstableloader ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just copy the `data/` directory of a production node in one cluster to another node in a DR cluster. You can only clone the data in application keyspaces from one cluster to another. The system tables (particularly `system.local`) is *universally* unique to each node and cannot be duplicated.

What you need to do is build a fresh cluster in DR that is configured as its own separate cluster. Once it is up and running, you can then start cloning the tables of the application keyspaces of the production DR from snapshots.

For details of how to clone application data, see the detailed procedured I documented in [How do I migrate data in tables to a new Cassandra cluster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316520/). Cheers!

Comment: HI @erick, is it possible to use common NFS storage as data_directory for more than one cassandra container....that way not using native replication but simply storage replication

Comment: @naxoki please post a new question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra with the details of your setup and I'd be happy to respond. Cheers!